# All game entities in one list or several lists by type?

Tags: collision-detection

Do video games typically attempt to keep one list of entities and update them in response to their type? Or, as is starting to seem more convenient, keep each type in it's own list, or at least generalize and have a few different lists?

In my particular example, I have one list with all types thrown in and check them for type, operating on them as needed. The same list is run through the physics engine and rendering engine. Now I'm starting to add types that need to react with others of the same type in one way and with the player in another.

For example, the 'Enemy' type needs to check for collision with other 'Enemies' to avoid stacking (2D game), while needing to be checked against the player for collision as well. If the Enemies were all in one list it would sure be easier.

More than anything I'm looking for a best practice. I realize each game is different and one size won't fit all, but there must be some general wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know usualy there are several lists used in a game for several purposes, for example they use some kind of object heirarchy so they can easily track all object positions and in the other hand they keep same pointers all in a linear array for all physical things they need to do. I mean there is no limit how many times you can have a refrence to an object and a pointer usualy has a very small cost (4 bytes per one), so as long as you can track all the pointers to some instance I think the best way is to make several list of them for different purposes. in your example for managing scene I would prefer some tree(parent-child) data structure, it helps alot when you can set object positions relatively, and create several lists of colliders and collidies for collision tests in physics engine all again with the same pointers used in scene manager.

Comment: Even though my game is a tiny pac-man-inspired affair, this advice made a big difference in it's organization.

Answer (score 0):

For collisions, using lists alone will quickly eat up performance, because of the exponential nature of checking each new object against all existing objects.

To keep things running smoothly, there is usually a broad-phase collision detection method to only compare objects that are within a reasonable proximity to each other.

Two common methods in 2D games for this are grids, and quad trees.

Here is a fairly good explanation of quad trees written for actionscript:
http://lab.polygonal.de/2007/09/09/quadtree-demonstration/

This forum makes a good explanation of the relative merits of Quad Trees vs grids.

But using either one will greatly speed up your collision loop over simply comparing lists.